# A Beautiful Soup script with two variables in the URL

Tags: python, variables, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape this website. I need a script which can put the name in the "who=" part of the URL and also the number of the page that I want to scrape in the "page=".

This is the current script :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import re
import pandas as pd
from colorama import Fore, Style

def main(url):
    names = ["Bryan", "David", "Robert"]
    with requests.Session() as req:
        data = []
    for name in names:
        for page in range(1, 9):
            print(url.format(Fore.RED + name + Style.RESET_ALL, Fore.YELLOW + str(page) + Style.RESET_ALL))
            print(f"Extracting Page# {page}")

            r = req.get(url.format(page))
            soup = bs(r.content, 'html.parser')

            names = [name.text for name in soup.select("h2.name.title.inbl")]
            address = [address.text for address in soup.select("div.h4.address.mtreset")]
            phone = [ph.group(1) for ph in re.finditer(r'mainLine&quot;:&quot;(\d+)', r.text)]
            for x, y, z in zip(names, address, phone):
                if z.startswith(("06", "07")):
                    data.append([x, y, z])
                    print(z)

        df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["Name", "Address", "Phone"])
        print(df)
        df.to_csv(r'C:////////.csv', index=False)
        print("Data Saved to your csv")

main("https://www.#########.com/search?part=1&who={}&page={}")
```

Please can someone explain me what is the problem and eventually rectify this script ?

Thank you very much by advance

Comment: I believe that has been addressed before within your previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61470986/failing-to-create-the-data-frame-and-populating-its-data-into-the-csv-file-prope/61471387?noredirect=1#comment108776381_61471387)

Comment: Hello @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη thank you for your message. Not exactly, I asked for it in this new question because my script doesn't work properly

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is that You are assigning the values in a `print` statement and not to the actual url variable

```
print(url.format(Fore.RED + name + Style.RESET_ALL, Fore.YELLOW + str(page) + Style.RESET_ALL))
```

and here you are using the url after assigning only one value

```
r = req.get(url.format(page))
```

here is two different approaches :

Approach 1

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import re
import pandas as pd
from colorama import Fore, Style

def main(url):
    names = ["Bryan", "David", "Robert"]
    with requests.Session() as req:
        data = []
        for name in names:
            for page in range(1, 9):
                url = url.format(Fore.RED + name + Style.RESET_ALL, Fore.YELLOW + str(page) + Style.RESET_ALL)
                print(url)
                print(f"Extracting Page# {page}")

                r = req.get(url)
                soup = bs(r.content, 'html.parser')

                names = [name.text for name in soup.select("h2.name.title.inbl")]
                address = [address.text for address in soup.select("div.h4.address.mtreset")]
                phone = [ph.group(1) for ph in re.finditer(r'mainLine&quot;:&quot;(\d+)', r.text)]
                for x, y, z in zip(names, address, phone):
                    if z.startswith(("06", "07")):
                        data.append([x, y, z])
                        print(z)

            df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["Name", "Address", "Phone"])
            print(df)
            df.to_csv(r'C:////////.csv', index=False)
            print("Data Saved to your csv")

main("https://www.#########.com/search?part=1&who={}&page={}")
```

Approach 2

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import re
import pandas as pd
from colorama import Fore, Style

def main(url):
    names = ["Bryan", "David", "Robert"]
    with requests.Session() as req:
        data = []
        for name in names:
            for page in range(1, 9):

                url_parm = {
                            'part'  : 1
                            ,'who'   : Fore.RED + name + Style.RESET_ALL
                            ,'page' : Fore.YELLOW + str(page) + Style.RESET_ALL
                            }

                print(f"Extracting Page# {page}")

                r = req.get(url , params = url_parm)
                soup = bs(r.content, 'html.parser')

                names = [name.text for name in soup.select("h2.name.title.inbl")]
                address = [address.text for address in soup.select("div.h4.address.mtreset")]
                phone = [ph.group(1) for ph in re.finditer(r'mainLine&quot;:&quot;(\d+)', r.text)]
                for x, y, z in zip(names, address, phone):
                    if z.startswith(("06", "07")):
                        data.append([x, y, z])
                        print(z)

            df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["Name", "Address", "Phone"])
            print(df)
            df.to_csv(r'C:////////.csv', index=False)
            print("Data Saved to your csv")

main("https://www.#########.com/search")
```

Comment: Hello @ahmedsoliman , thank you very much for your answer. Another problem : the first approach only works for the first page. It does "page=1" , "page=1" , "page=1" ... And the second approach doesn't scrape nothing I don't know why :/

Comment: @ChristianHEREDIA the two approaches works but I can't tell what's wrong without having the website url